# "read_excel" in a Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, xlsx

I have a Shiny app that uses the `read.xlsx` function from package `xlsx`. All works fine, but I want to change to `read_excel` from `readxl`, hoping it would be faster and able to cope with large files.

ui part:

```
fileInput("inputFile","Upload file...")
```

server part:

```
  data <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$inputFile
    if (is.null(inFile)) { return(NULL) }    
    dataFile <- read_excel(inFile$datapath,sheet=1)
    return(dataFile)
  })
```

I get the "Unknown format" error.

> inFile$datapath is "/tmp/.../60974676c7287e913d1c0dc5/0" 
>   inFile$type is "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"

Question 1: is there a way to tell `read_excel` that it's a xlsx type file?
Question 2: is it possible to control the location where the uploaded file will be stored?

Comment: Have you tried it in the *R* console with the same input file?

Comment: Yes, in R console it works.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This was an [open issue](https://github.com/hadley/readxl/issues/85) with the readxl package.  The current workaround provided there is to copy the file data path and append `.xlsx`.  Here is a working example on my machine limited to `.xlsx` files edited to use `file.rename` instead of `file.copy`.

```
library(shiny)
library(readxl)

runApp(
    list(
        ui = fluidPage(
            titlePanel("Use readxl"),
            sidebarLayout(
                sidebarPanel(
                    fileInput('file1', 'Choose xlsx file',
                              accept = c(".xlsx")
                              )
                    ),
                mainPanel(
                    tableOutput('contents'))
                )
            ),
        server = function(input, output){
            output$contents <- renderTable({
                inFile <- input$file1

                if(is.null(inFile))
                    return(NULL)
                file.rename(inFile$datapath,
                          paste(inFile$datapath, ".xlsx", sep=""))
                read_excel(paste(inFile$datapath, ".xlsx", sep=""), 1)
            })
        }
        )
    )
```

**EDIT**
Note that with the `1.1.0` version of `readxl` it no longer needs to have the file renamed.  The following works without a problem for me now.

```
library(shiny)
library(readxl)

runApp(
  list(
    ui = fluidPage(
      titlePanel("Use readxl"),
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          fileInput('file1', 'Choose xlsx file',
                    accept = c(".xlsx")
          )
        ),
        mainPanel(
          tableOutput('contents'))
      )
    ),
    server = function(input, output){
      output$contents <- renderTable({

        req(input$file1)

        inFile <- input$file1

        read_excel(inFile$datapath, 1)
      })
    }
  )
)
```

Comment: Can you just rename it with `file.rename`? You'll likely need to clean up manually, but that is necessary anyway.

Answer (score 1):

to ensure that the user does upload an .xlsx file, or you need to check the extension you're self to switch between read functions. You can extract the extension as following:

```
library(shiny)
library(readxl)

runApp(
list(
    ui = fluidPage(
        titlePanel("Use readxl"),
        sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel(
                fileInput('file1', 'Choose xlsx file',
                          accept = c(".xlsx")
                          )
                ),
            mainPanel(
                tableOutput('contents'))
            )
        ),
    server = function(input, output){
        output$contents <- renderTable({
            inFile <- input$file1

            if(is.null(inFile))
                return(NULL)

            ext <- tools::file_ext(inFile$name)
            file.rename(inFile$datapath,
               paste(inFile$datapath, ext, sep="."))
            read_excel(paste(inFile$datapath, ext, sep="."), 1)
         })
        }
    )
)
```