# missing file extension using Shiny drag & drop feature

Tags: shiny

Using the new Shiny drag&drop feature when dropping an xls file I get an odd error "missing file extension":

```
Output created: /tmp/RtmpOu52HQ/file916414ce2376.html
Warning in body(fun) : argument is not a function
Warning: Error in : Missing file extension.
Stack trace (innermost first):
    107: excel_format
    106: read_excel_
    105: read_excel
    104: eval
    103: eval
    .....
```

I just drop a xls (with extensión of course) file and parse with readxl but this error is annoying me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Missing file extension` is (was?) a common problem when reading excel files into shiny apps. This provides you with the known solutions for integrating reading excel files (or multiple sheets) into your shiny:

1. with `file.rename()` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45435188/cant-read-excel-files-in-r-shiny/45435953#45435953)
2. with `file.copy()` [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/readxl/issues/85)